# Preparing a MBR in a file

Tags: windows-10, vmware-fusion

I am working with VMWare Fusion 7 on Windows 10 and I would like to edit the MBR of a virtual disc. That is, I would like to be able to edit the MBR in a more favorable way.

For this instance, I want to change the ID of a drive in the MBR.

I already found the `vm-pt.vmdk` which turns out to be a MBR. How do I edit it now?

Comment: Is there a problem in using the guest OS' partitioning tools?

Comment: @Hannu I could not find one for Win10 that would just let me edit the MBR similar to fdisk, but also the drive IDs (which fdisk seems to lack). Is there one you maybe could recommend?